# Solving a partial differential equation with initial value $0$ but a boundary condition with non-zero space derivative

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have a function $f(x,t)$ given by:
$$f(x,t)=\cases{0 , & $x \le x_c$ \\  f_2(x,t), & $x>x_c$}$$
of which $f_2(x)$ satisfies the following partial differential equation:
$$\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial t}=-c\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}+D\frac{\partial^2f_2}{\partial x^2}$$

where $c,D$ are constants with boundary conditions:

1. $f_2(x,0)=0$
2. $f_2(\infty,t)=0$
3. $\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}=\sigma(t) \,\,\,\,\, \text{at} \,\,\, x=x_c$

Mathematically, due to the initial condition $1$, it seems that $f_2=0$ will be the solution. But intuition says that due to condition $3$, $f_2$ will have a non-zero evolution with time.

How to solve this?

Comment: Is condition 2. $f_2(x_c,t)=0$ ,and if not is $x_c$ smaller or greater than $0$ ?

Comment: @Delta-u Apologise for the mistake. I have corrected the condition and $x_c>0$.

Comment: The condition at $x=\infty$ seems tricky, is a condition like $|f_2(x)| \in L^2$ sufficient for your problem ? If so you can use Lax-Milgram-like argument to show existence of solutions.

Comment: @Delta-u Actually f is probability. So $0<f<1$. And apart from existence, can you suggest me a way to solve the equation?

Comment: Perhaps multidimensional Laplace transform can make it easier to solve?

Comment: The Laplace transform is indeed a great idea :-)

Comment: @Emil I tried Fourier transform but it didnt help. I will try Laplace and see what happens. And 1D laplace with x as variable should suffice. Isnt it?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat: I don't know how the left hand side would work, perhaps one need to justify moving the time derivative outside the integral. But I remember laplace integrates from zero and up, so it seems suitable :)

Comment: Is $\sigma(t)$ any function ? It seems that you need information about $\mathcal{L}(\sigma)(Dp^2-cp)$ alongside line $p=p_0+i\mathbb{R}$ in order to have the inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: @Delta-u Yes it is a known function.